# Get Apple Events from AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-carbon, appleevents

I have a simple AppleScript which tells me url of active window in specific browser

```
tell application "Opera"
   get URL of active tab of window 1
end tell
```

However I would like to see Apple Events needed to run that script, probable some of these: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/apple_events?language=objc
My final goal is to code same script but using Apple Core Services.

I have checked Script Editor but I do not see any tab or menu where that information is displayed. Is there any way to translate that script?

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: Why? Building Apple events from scratch is a royal pain and the old C API is particularly arcane and gnarly. Best approach is to call into AppleScript via the [AppleScript-ObjC bridge](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html), which makes AppleScript script objects and handlers appear as Cocoa classes/instances and methods to your ObjC/Swift code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are several such ways. My favorite is to use [Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com), which just translates the AppleScript into raw Apple events for you. Alternatively, you can run your AppleScript in an environment where `export AEDebugSends=1; export AEDebugReceives=1` has been [turned on](https://red-sweater.com/blog/227/scripting-the-hard-way).

Comment: I have tried both ways and i see this: {core,getd target='psn '[Opera] {----={form=prop,want=prop,seld=URL ,from={form=prop,want=prop,seld=acTa,from={form=indx,want=cwin,seld=1,from=NULL-impl}}}} attr:{csig=65536 returnID=15130}
Could you help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: Yes but not in the comments to this question.  I answered correcting the question you asked; your comment proves that. That is the raw Apple event you asked for. The fact that you don’t know how to read it is another matter.

Comment: added new question then, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638803/translate-into-apple-events-applescript